# JMS Point-to-Point in jmeter

Tags: jms, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

Reg: JMeter Point-to-Point

Could you please tell how to get the `QueueConnnectionFaction`

And `ContextConnectionFactory`

Can anyone help me in configuring `JNDI` properties in `JMS POINT-TO-POINT` of JMETER

```
ERROR - jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.JMSSampler: progress/message/jclient/TopicConnectionFactory java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: progress/message/jclient/TopicConnectionFactory
```

Please provide some solution.

Comment: Any news on my answer ? You should accept it if it was OK

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't put a dependency jar from your jms provider, see:

- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: progress/message/jclient/TopicConnectionFactory

Answer (score 0):

The `QueueConnnectionFactory` is the container of the queues that is created before the queues. I used to use the Hermes JMS application to get this information but you could get it from WebLogic too.

For example, the next image shows my configuration, using the information of `binding` for  the `QueueConnectionFactory` field, and using the information of `initialContextFactory` for the `InitialContextFactory` field, and do not forget to use the `providerURL` in the `ProviderURL` field.

[image: image1]

In this example I am not getting the response. For this reason, I am only putting the name of my requester queue.

Ensure that the information is correct. In the `JMS Properties` you could use Headers for the request.

[image: image2]

[image: image3]